# How to you make a Javascript object's method call setInterval with an object method as an argument

Tags: javascript, methods, setinterval, countdown

I am trying to create a generic countdown timer object in Javascript
I have a method (decrementTimer) that reduces the timeLeft on counter by a fixed amount and another method which uses setInterval to call decrementTimer method.

The problem is that the code only runs once not every second. It looks like setInterval isn't putting the decrementTimer function on the queue inside my object.

I have tried making javascript do an Eval by putting the keyword "window" in front of the setIntervalfunction call but this doesn't work.

I can't use a Javascript class because I can't assume that all browsers support ECMAScript 6. I am using IE11.

I have also found solutions that work when you are doing this in a function but no examples of how to make this work in an object.

I would appreciate some help.

```
<script>
var myTimer = {
    timeLeft:       10,
    timerJobNumber: null,  
    decrementTimer: function(){
    alert("decrementTimer called. timeLeft = " + this.timeLeft);
    this.timeLeft = this.timeLeft - 1;
        if(this.timeLeft<0){
            alert("done");
        }
    },
    startTimer: function(){
    alert("startTimer called");
    this.timerJobNumber = window.setInterval(this.decrementTimer(),10);
    alert("Interval Job Number = " + this.timerJobNumber);
               },

    stopTimer: function(){
    clearInterval(this.timerJobNumber);
    alert(this.timerJobNumber);
    alert("job terminated");
    },

    resetTimer: function(initialTime){
    this.TimeLeft = initialTime;
    alert("intitialTime="+intitialTime);
    },
    getTimeLeft: function(){
        return this.timeLeft;
    }  
};

console.log(myTimer.getTimeLeft());
console.log(myTimer.startTimer() );
console.log(myTimer.getTimeLeft());

</script>
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do here, but setInterval first argument expects a function, so first of all you would have to replace `window.setInterval(this.decrementTimer(), ...` with `window.setInterval(this.decrementTimer, ...`

Comment: There are a bunch of weird things about this code, but one thing I noticed is that your `setInterval` interval parameter is set to `10`. This is `10` milliseconds, not seconds. That's instantaneous to the human eye. `1000` is 1 second. Also, I think it would be best when working with a timer to *not* use alert methods. It interrupts the page. I would suggest a `console` method like `log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really check all of your code, but this seems to do what you want :

```
var myTimer = {
    timeLeft:       10,
    timerJobNumber: null,  
    decrementTimer: function(){
        console.log("decrementTimer called. timeLeft = " + this.timeLeft);
        this.timeLeft = this.timeLeft - 1;
        if(this.timeLeft<0){
            this.stopTimer();
        }
    },
    startTimer: function(){
        this.timerJobNumber = window.setInterval(this.decrementTimer.bind(this),1000);
        console.log("Interval Job Number = " + this.timerJobNumber);
    },

    stopTimer: function(){
        clearInterval(this.timerJobNumber);
        alert(this.timerJobNumber);
    },

    resetTimer: function(initialTime){
        this.TimeLeft = initialTime;
        alert("intitialTime="+intitialTime);
    },
    getTimeLeft: function(){
        return this.timeLeft;
    }  
};
```

Note that you can easily transform this into a *class like* function :

```
var MyTimer = function() {
    this.timeLeft = 10;
    this.timerJobNumber = null;
};

MyTimer.prototype.decrementTimer = function() {
    console.log("decrementTimer called. timeLeft = " + this.timeLeft);
    this.timeLeft = this.timeLeft - 1;
    if(!this.timeLeft > 0)
        this.stopTimer();
};

MyTimer.prototype.startTimer = function() {
    this.timerJobNumber = window.setInterval(this.decrementTimer.bind(this),1000);
    console.log("Interval Job Number = " + this.timerJobNumber);
};

MyTimer.prototype.stopTimer = function() {
    clearInterval(this.timerJobNumber);
    alert(this.timerJobNumber);
};

MyTimer.prototype.resetTimer = function(initialTime) {
    this.timeLeft = initialTime;
    alert("intitialTime="+intitialTime);
};

MyTimer.prototype.getTimeLeft = function() {
    return this.timeLeft;
};

//...

var m = new MyTimer();
m.startTimer();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the protocol is to thank contributors individually or collectively. Thanks Everyone for helping me out. I had been struggling with this for weeks!

Comment: @JudgeMoody You can thank anyone you want, it's always a nice thing to read :) You should also mark your question as resolved by selecting the most helpful answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't bind your `decrementTimer()` inside the `setInterval()` function.

```
startTimer: function(){
    alert("startTimer called");
    this.timerJobNumber = window.setInterval(this.decrementTimer.bind(this),10);
    alert("Interval Job Number = " + this.timerJobNumber);
}
```

if you are not familiar  this topic, then follow this link. I think it will help you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed. I hadn't come across the "bind" keyword before.